# Don't raw strings treat backslashes as a literal character?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a question about the backslashes when using the `re` module in python. Consider the code:

```py
import re
message = 'My phone number is 345-298-2372'
num_reg = re.compile(r'\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d') 
match = num_reg.search(message)
print(match.group())
```

In the code above, a **raw string** is passed into the `re.compile` method, but the backslash is still not treated as a literal character, as `/d` remain a placeholder for a digit. Why the raw string then?

Comment: ... because that's what the `\d` means in regex? In this particular case, the raw string doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Loocid no, it wouldn't be. `r'\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d'` and `'\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d'` produce the same string.  i.e. `r'\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d' == '\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d'`

Comment: `\d` is not a special sequence that needs escaping, using it in a raw or "normal" string does not make a difference. Things like `\n` (a newline char) are where raw strings produce the 2 literal chars rather than the single char. There is a table of the "escape sequences" in Python here https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Comment: Take a look at the docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It does do something.  Prevents _DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \d_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague) for re and raw strings answers this question well.

So in your example the parameter passed to re.compile() ends up containing the original `\`. This is desirable when working with re because it has its own escape sequences that may or may not conflict with python's escape sequences. Typically it's much more convenient to use `r'foo'` when working with regex so you don't have to double escape your regex special characters.

Without the raw string, for the escape character to make it to re for processing you would need to use:

```py
import re
message = 'My phone number is 345-298-2372'
num_reg = re.compile('\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d\\d') 
match = num_reg.search(message)
print(match.group())
```

You may consider looking at regex quantifier/repetition syntax as it generally makes re more readable:

```py
import re
message = 'My phone number is 345-298-2372'
num_reg = re.compile(r'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}') 
match = num_reg.search(message)
print(match.group())
```

Comment: More useful documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague